# How to change src of an iron-image element of Google Polymer

Tags: polymer

Thank you very much. I finally got a good result. The problem was that I did not understand the standard usage of the function getUrl() which is provided by Google.

New question:
Reading the valuable answers, I think about the remaining problem as follows.
Let me ask how to change the src value of an iron-page object after it has been set the initial src value, within the context of the old question.

Old question:
Let me ask about Google polymer.
Here follows some code from my project.
I simply want to change the src of an iron-image element.
I tested two versions for the "ready" function. However both failed to change the src of the iron-image element. Could you point out where is wrong in my code?

```
    <iron-image id="id1" src="[[mysrc]]"></iron-image>

    Polymer({

    properties { mysrc = { type:String , notify:true } },

    (version 1) ready: function() { mysrc = getUrl(); }

    (version 2) ready: function() { this.$.id1.src = getUrl(); }

    })
```

In details, alert(getUrl()) shows the expected correct string.

Comment: There is no reason why your code shouldn't work. Could you post a more complete example here or on Plunker, JSbins, etc?

Comment: changing the `mysrc` value from any function using `this.mysrc={something}` should change the value of `src`

Comment: Please prefer a new thread for a new question. You can always answer your own question if you got the answer. You can also put a link for old question in new one if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that you're not invoking your properties and methods from the right context? To set a property and call a method you need to reference them from `this`. In other words,

```
--- ready: function() { mysrc = getUrl(); }
+++ ready: function() { this.mysrc = this.getUrl(); }
```

Here's a JS Bin that properly handles the scenario you're describing:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37811023">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="http://polygit.org/components/">
  <script href="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="iron-image/iron-image.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">
</head>

<body>
  <dom-module id="my-el">
    <template>
      <iron-image src="[[url]]"></iron-image>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-el',
        properties: {
          url: {
            type: String,
            notify: true
          }
        },
        ready: function(e) {
          this.url = this.getUrl();
        },
        getUrl: function() {
          return 'http://lorempixel.com/300/300';
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
  <my-el></my-el>
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/wanemi/edit?html,output

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helps me a lot. For my context, it did not work. Probably because my getUrl() is too late so that it returns the url after the iron-page has been set its initial src value, a null value. So probably, my final problem is simple. That is, how to change the src value of the iron-image after it has been set the initial src value.

Comment: @KayceBasques FYI, I noticed you've been linking to **http**://jsbin.com, which ends up being redirected to **https**://jsbin.com. The demo's `<base>` points to **http**, which leads to a `Mixed Content` error and a blank page.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @tony19

Answer (score 0):

You should try

`ready: function() { this.mysrc = getUrl(); }`

or

`ready: function() { this.set('mysrc', getUrl());`

In version 1 you reference a variable that don't exist, because a property is bind to `this`.

In version 2 should work.

Comment: following your answer, I tried both versions again, but got the same bad results. The "src" did not change. The version one yields no error whereas version two is said that: "this.$.id1.src" is undefined.